# Make methods with name in english but call them in spanish in c# project?

Tags: c#, localization

I am making a C# project for a client and my class have methods with is signature in english, something like `Connect`, `Disconnect`, `Rebuild`, etc. But my client, in his application manage everything in spanish. Can my library project maintain the method names in English but allowing my client to call the methods in spanish? like `Conectar`, `Desconectar`, `Recompilar`? Maybe some decoration on the method or something like that?

Comment: You could put attributes with the supported languages above each method, then use reflection to find them, but ugh... Standard localization won't work because the function names are just symbols to the compiler.

Comment: The .Net library method names are in English; why should yours differ? Better question: why is he [not using English](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/) in his own method names?

Comment: There's no easy way to accomplish this.  You could come reasonably close to the spirit of what I think you're looking to accomplish here by being diligent about making your XML code comments multilingual.

Answer (score 4):

Bluntly put: No.
As a last resort you could write a wrapper around your class with the method names in Spanish, calling the English variants internally, but I wouldn't.

Personally, I think Connect / Disconnect / Rebuild are common programming terms that every programmer should be familiar with, whatever language he/she speaks.

Comment: Connect / Disconnect / Rebuild where some samples.. there are more things.. besides, some methods already are in my client app and i am rewriting those methods.

Comment: I understand, I even doubted if I should include it as an edit in the answer, as it may sound a bit harsh, or arrogant, the proper English word eludes me currently. But I do feel, like Tim S. mentioned in his comment, that, since the *whole* framework is in English, why make exceptions for the rest? I'm currently working for a client in Holland, and the mixed-language method names just make me cringe. There's even methods with names like "GetWachtwoordForUser" (GetPasswordForUser), half Dutch, half English. It's ugly as hell, and doesn't parse well while reading.

Comment: I know.. it's a shame but i cannot change my client's code.

Comment: No shame. Different people prefer different things. In your case, if I understand the situation correctly, I would use Spanish words for naming stuff in the library that you're building for your client. Ultimately, that's what your customer prefers, they pay, you provide.

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard way of making an alias is just to have the alias call the original method.

```
public void Conectar(){
    Connect();
}
```

Comment: There's no "standard" way of doing this, because it's fundamentally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

For the love of bits and bytes - **Don't do this!**  But the answer is:

```
#if (SPANISH)
    public void Conectar()
#else
    public void Connect()
#endif
    {
        // implementation goes here...
    }
```

Then have two builds where one is built with `SPANISH` defined, and the other not defined (aka English build).
Obviously no interoperability: code written against Spanish version of library won't be able to use English version.

If I haven't mentioned it, for the love of bits and bytes...

Oh! And you'll have a bit of trouble when you're trying to call public functions from within your code.  You'll either would have to surround every single time with `#if` just like above, or for every public one, call underlying English based implementation helper like:

```
#if (SPANISH)
    public void Conectar()
#else
    public void Connect()
#endif
    {
        return ConnectImpl()
    }

    private void ConnectImpl()
    {
        // Actual implementation here...
    }
```

... which of course will get even more complex if you have return values :)

For the love of bits and bytes...

Answer (score 0):

You could add an attribute to the method.  But that will only be useful if you use reflection to call the method.

If you did want to make methods

```
public void Conectar(){
    Connect();
}
```

I would put them in a partial class so they aren't in the same file as your main class.

Then you could optionally compile english-only or spanish only.

If you wanted to  you could:

Have all your methods named things like "ConnectImpl"
  Have an English partial class

```
public void Connect()
{
    ConnectImpl();
}
```

Have a Spanish partial class with methods like:

```
public void Conectar()
{
    ConnectImpl();
}
```

Then you optionally compile one or the other.  Seems like a pain though.